# Leave a job early to go back to former employer?

Tags: ethics, quitting

## Background

I worked for Company X for 10 years. They were a large company, I moved around and got to know a lot of people. The last year or so I felt stifled and like I wasn't developing technically, like I'd get stuck doing the same procedural things so I left on good terms giving long notice and starting a new job with the well wishing of former colleagues.

I am two months into new job. A colleague I had spoken with about possibly coming back to work for in 2-3 years started getting responsibilities sooner than normal wants me back and is verbally throwing around offers that would be a 20% raise from the current job.

Current job is turning out to not be exactly what I thought. It's sort of like I thought I was taking a Systems Administrator job, and that's what my title and pay are, but I do 99% tech support alongside other people who are both Tech Support in job title and Systems Administrator in job title. The whole reason I took this job was technical development. However, I don't believe the hiring manager intentionally misled me, I think I didn't ask enough questions and maybe looked at the situation through rose-colored glasses. The final hiccup is, current job is a career federal position. So the usual advice that your employer wouldn't hesitate to fire you isn't as true, and the amount they had to invest to hire me as well as train me is not insignificant.

## Personal considerations

My commute is worse, my office environment is worse, and of course I miss a lot of the people I worked with for 10 years. The folks here are nice, but the turnover is higher and the comradery not as strong.

## Quandary

Everyone in my personal life, as well as my colleague from former employer, suggest I should take the money and run. Former colleague might be patient, but I don't know how much I want to test that. Also yes I don't have a written offer yet, but I suspect as soon as I say 'yes i'm ready to come back' I'd have one quickly, and don't want to burn former colleague by waiting until then to make the decision. I'm also confident the job would be better than my current job, though it's possible it won't be great, I won't really know until I do it. I'm concerned with the moral/ethical implications of leaving my job so early. Nobody misled me. On the other hand, 20% is a huge pay bump that would likely take me 10+ years here to earn, I don't like my job, and the opportunity may not wait for me. Also this is only my second professional experience in the field. Leaving it on my resume would look bad should I ever decide to leave former employer, but leaving it off will mean I look like I've only ever worked for one shop.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is about the money for you, and that's a good thing because if the old job was "the same" except for a 20% increase, that raise alone would probably not be enough for career satisfaction.

Comment: Seems like you've already reached your decision on the title question (i.e. you don't really like your current job for several reasons, you want the 20% raise, and you consider that position an improvement over your current one).  I don't think there's any serious doubt that you'll accept the offer?  If so, is the question here mostly about how to minimize the potential negative consequences of moving back (resume-wise, for instance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Understanding job satisfaction

Job satisfaction is a measure of yourself (your capacity to work, willingness to work and opportunity to work), the work effort have to expel to complete your work and the organisational support behind you.

The amount of contribution you will feel happy giving an organisation is strongly linked to the inducements (remuneration, support, training) that the company is providing you.

In this case you mentioned that you don't like your job. It doesn't sound like this is a company providing you enough organisational support or training to outweigh you not feeling like you're receiving adequate remuneration for your efforts. In this case, I think you aren't going to find happiness here without a significant change in your role, and I think you should leave. Your work is likely to suffer over time if you continue to feel unhappy with the position and it sounds like the situation isn't likely to change anytime soon without action from your end.

## Will it affect your resume?

Personally, I don't think so. Not every engagement has to be a perfect one and hiring managers completely understand this. Provided you don't have a number of small stints on your resume it's not going to reflect badly on you if you list this one small window of work. That said, if you've only been there two months and have 10 years of work history in Company A, I also don't think it will hurt you if you leave it off. 10 years work experience, even in the same company, is a great amount of experience. I wouldn't be too concerned about this.

Comment: I suggest, in the resume, listing the different positions you have had at Company X separately (maybe under a Company X heading).  That way, it won't say "2 employers, one for 10+ years and one very brief, but rather, "8 positions, 1 very brief."  That would look significantly better.  When asked about it (and almost everyone *will* ask), just smile, shrug, and say while shaking your head gently, "it wasn't at all what I expected."  Do what you can to minimize the impact on the current employer, so you can add that to your answer. Bonus: it will put them on notice to be truthful to you.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you have already answered your question. Everything you have said points to you taking the 20% increase in pay as the better option. The sooner you show your interest and get it in writing the better. Until then work well where you are because nothing is definite yet.

The only thing I would mention is that you have only been with your present position for two months, you're not really settled in yet. So if you gave it a chance you'd probably get used to it eventually. Having said that...

What are you waiting for? Go get that pay increase and keep moving forwards.

Answer (score 5):

You moved from X to Y. Now you might get your old job back, getting 20% more money, a better commute, more interesting work... Why are you asking at all? Talk to the old company, and if you get an offer and a signed contract then you give notice at the new company.

The situation is slightly different from the usual advice that you shouldn't accept a counter offer when you are leaving. In that case you are the lousy employee who wants to run away and is only kept by more money, and who cannot be trusted anymore. In your case you are the good employee who realised that leaving was a mistake and will never think of leaving again.

Comment: The OP sort of answered their own question. And by "sort of", I mean "definitely".